# dynamic URL with API paramethers

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new in nextjs and I need to do a dynamic URL using one API parameter
I have some like this data for the API

```
[
  {
    "categories" : {
            "department": "HR"
            "location": "xxxx"
     },
    "id": "4d2f341-k4kj6h7g-juh5v3",

  },
  {
    "categories" : {
            "department": "Operarions"
            "location": "xxxx"
     },
    "id": "4qd3452-fsd34-jfd3453",

  },
  {
    "categories" : {
            "department": "Marketing"
            "location": "xxxx"
     },
    "id": "4d2f341-k4kwer37g-juh5v3",

  },

]
```

And I need to do something like that in my index.js

```
return(
      <h1>More details</h1>
     <a href="https://page.com/${id}"> link <a>
)
```

If someone can help me pls

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to generate dynamic pages from that API data? How does that relate to the snippet from the `index.js` file you showed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, will try to help you

Imagine you have a folder with the name `records`, so your url will be `/records`

In data you provided, you have several categories with `ids` which ones you like to have as links.(generated records dynamically)

According to nextjs docs, you can create `getStaticProps` page and generate static pages (it means it's very good for SEO, so use it on visible by SEO pages)

Imagine you have the next structure:

/records

- [pid].tsx (or js)
- index.tsx

This structure means that if you go to `/records` URL your index file will be triggered. And for `/records/4d2f341-k4kj6h7g-juh5v3` your [pid] file will be triggered.

**in index.tsx**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const Records= ({ records }) => {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Records</h1>
            {records.map(record=> (
                <div>
                    <Link href={'/records/' + record.id} key={record.id}>  
                        <a>
                            {record.categories.department}
                        </a>     
                    </Link>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    //your API path here
    const res = await fetch('replace_by_your_api_route');
    const data =  await res.json()
    return {
        props: {records: data}
    }
}

export default Records
```

**in your [pid].tsx**

```
import GeneralUtils from "lib/generalUtils";

const RecordDetails= ({record}) => {

    return(
        <div>
            {record? 
            <div >
                {record.categories.department} {record.categories.location}
            </div>
            : ''}
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const pid = context.params.pid;
    //your api path to get each record where pid it is your parameter you are passssing to your api.
    const res = await fetch(process.env.APIpath + '/api/public/getRecord?pid=' + (pid));
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        props: {record: data}
    }
}   
    
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    
    const res = await fetch('your_api_path_same_as_in_index_tsx')
    const posts = await res.json()
  
    // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
    const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
      //your id of each record, for example 4d2f341-k4kj6h7g-juh5v3
      params: { pid: post.id.toString() },
    }))
    
    // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
    // { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
    // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
    return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
  }


export default ProductDetails;
```

**Output:** - user types

`/records` - he will have list of recods with links

`/records/4d2f341-k4kj6h7g-juh5v3` - he will have page with info of d2f341-k4kj6h7g-juh5v3

Check this [info](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#example) very carefully and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zueyEdRZQlk)